# Force horizontal node order in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I have a graph in TikZ.
It can be planar, and I know what change I need to make to make it planar but I can't work out how to communicate this to TikZ.

**I wish to force the NTN node to be to the left of the RvNN and/or RNN nodes.
Which sounds fairly simple.**

[image: graph]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
sibling sep=20mm,level sep=10mm, node distance=10mm
]
\graph[layered layout]{%
NN -> { NTN, RNN, AE };
RvNN -> { RvNTN,RvNTN, RAE};
RNN ->RvNN;
NTN-> RvNTN;
AE->RAE;

};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is fairly easy for me to look at many graphs and say what node order swaps need to be made so they can be drawn planar.

But a few related questions:

- [Why does PGF/TikZ 3.0 draw my simple layered graph as non-planar by default?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171990/why-does-pgf-tikz-3-0-draw-my-simple-layered-graph-as-non-planar-by-default)
- [Use "layered layout" with user-specified node ordering (i.e., without crossing minimization)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173540/use-layered-layout-with-user-specified-node-ordering-i-e-without-crossing-m)

Have got me thinking maybe this is very hard.

I tried fiddling with `edge weights` and `minimum layers`, but got no where, and mostly made things worse.

Comment: Did you try the `minimum layers` option as in your first link so that TikZ can try to detect the crossings? Also I think you need to put that branch earlier

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't see exactly how to apply it to make it detect the crossing as undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving `NTN -> RvNTN` up helps:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
sibling sep=20mm,level sep=10mm, node distance=10mm
]
\graph[layered layout]{%
NN -> { NTN, RNN, AE };
NTN-> RvNTN;
RvNN -> { RvNTN,RvNTN, RAE};
RNN ->RvNN;
AE->RAE;

};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Why does it help? What is there a general rule? That works for the MWE, but how should I apply it in future?  Should I just shuffle my node links til i get an order which works?

Comment: @Oxinabox From the documentation, crossing minimization uses a heuristics, because the problem is NP hard. Heuristics means, that not all cases are caught at the optimum. That means, there are cases, where manual intervention can improve the outcome.

Comment: I get that. But how can I use reordering the declaration in order to do manual intervention? It doesn't seem to be case of List the Left most Edges first? (or is it?)

Comment: @Oxinabox The order of branch specifications matters, as can be seen in the answer. `NN` has three outgoing edges, the version in the question, first uses `RNN`, then `NTN`, the answer switches these and calls `NTN->RvNTN` before `RNN->RvNN`. Since the result is cross-free, the crossing minimization algorithm has nothing to improve and therefore no reason for reordering.